# How to rout by angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm newbie in angular js I need to rout by the following code  but it get   HTTP Status 404  error

web console show this message

localhost:8080/testasd/addStudent Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

```
   var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);

  mainApp.config(['$routeProvider',
     function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
           when('/addStudent', {
              templateUrl: 'AddStudent.html',
              controller: 'AddStudentController'
           }).
           when('/viewStudents', {
              templateUrl: 'ViewStudents.html',
              controller: 'ViewStudentsController'
           }).
           otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/addStudent'
           });
     }]);

     mainApp.controller('AddStudentController', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = "This page will be used to display add student form";
     });

     mainApp.controller('ViewStudentsController', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = "This page will be used to display all the students";
     });
```

Comment: Do you want it to go to localhost:8080/testasd/addStudent or localhost:8080/addStudent?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your web server to send `index.html` for all URLs requested. This is called a rewrite rule. This is because the web browser will issue a `GET` request for that URL, and the web server expects to find a file in that location. A rewrite rule lets you intercept that request and redirect it to a different file.

The URL in your route doesn't exist on the web server, but AngularJS needs to be loaded. So send the `index.html` from the web root for all requests. This assumes you are creating what is called a *single page* app.

For Apache create a file called `.htaccess` in your web root

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [QSA,L]
 </IfModule>
```

For IIS create a file called `web.config` in your web root

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="angular" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```